# Javascript with auto dashes

Tags: javascript

I currently use the script below to take any form of information and pull out the numbers to make a phone number with dashes in it. However, if I accidently click in the field, it puts two dashes in there even though nothing was pasted or typed. Does JS have a way to say ONLY if something is pasted then add dashes? The reason it's a pain is I have 2 search fields, and if I want to use one, the other has to be blank. So if there are 2 dashes in it, I have to delete them out and hit enter in the same field or it will add them again.

I appreciate any help you might have.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function addDashes(f)
    {
        f.value = f.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        f.value = f.value.slice(0,3)+"-"+f.value.slice(3,6)+"-"+f.value.slice(6,15);
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: how are you calling the `addDashes` function?

Comment: check that `f.value` is not empty string before adding dashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you need, but this just checks to see if there is actually something there before formatting it:

```
function addDashes(f)
{
    var oldVal = f.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (oldVal.length) {
        f.value = oldVal.slice(0,3) + "-" + oldVal.slice(3,6) + "-" + oldVal.slice(6,15);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, I thought it might be helpful to bring up validation. I'm not sure if you are doing anything on the server-side to make sure it is a valid phone number, but it might be helpful to do a little validation so taht you don't add dashes if the user has just typed some spaces.

First, I would remove the non-numeric values before you check the length. I've updated the code above to do that.

Next, I would check against some length. Maybe you want to only add dashes if the number is at least 9 digits long. You can decide that length taht you watn to check against. In that case, you would add:

```
if (oldVal.length >= 9) { ...
```

It all depends on if/how you are validating this field.

Comment: One more comment, I thought there was a code for such. I appreciate you helping me with this. When I put a space in there, it does add the dashes (which is fine) but when I remove them, it stays gone. Perfect!

Comment: I've made some changes to my answer to reflect this comment. I think it is a good idea to do a bit of validating so that you don't add dashes after typing a space.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with something like this:

```
function addDashes(f) {
    f.value = f.value.replace(/(\d{3})-?(\d{3})-?(\d{9})/, '$1-$2-$3');
}
```

It'll only do something if you have 15 digits there (possibly with dashes already in place).